# Clause analysis for causative verbs

Tags: syntax, subordination, causative

I am doing clause analysis for a corpus and am not sure how to determine the clauses for the following type of sentence:

The kind of woman that makes people remember Marylin Monroe.

I suppose it should read like:

(she is) the kind of woman that makes people remember Marylin Monroe.

But do I analyze the sentence as if 'she is' weren't ellipted? I am also pretty lost on the causative 'make someone do something' (in terms of clause breakdown).

I would appreciate any and all help, thank you in advance!

Comment: Some propose that the subject of the subordinate clause (small clause) raises to the matrix clause. The subject of the small clause can be a reflexive of the matrix subject, which means that it is part of the matrix clause, even though it is semantically the agent of the small clause. E.g. "I made myself drink poison."

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

- *The kind of woman that makes people remember Marilyn Monroe.*

is not a sentence; it's a noun phrase. As Tom Robbins once put it, *This sentence no verb.*
If it occurs in a corpus, its context will tell you what's been deleted, if anything.

Second, the basic rule for clauses is that every non-auxiliary verb defines a clause. Thus,
if there are two verbs in an utterance, as here, there are two clauses.
(Neither one is a main clause, because this utterance is not a sentence.)

The bracketing would be something like

[np
     [np *the kind of woman* np]
       [s [np *that/who* np] [vp *makes* [np
         [s [np *people* np] [vp *remember* [np *Marilyn Monroe* np]  vp] s]
                                                                                  np]
                                                      vp]
               s]
      np]